# Finding linear asymptote

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

We have 
$$ f(x) = (2x^2-x^3)^{1/3} $$

A linear asymptote is like: $$y = px+q$$  $$p \not= 0$$

We had this definition in our lecture:$$ p = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}}
$$

so

$$ p = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{(2x^2-x^3)^\frac{1}{3}}{x}} $$ 
 $$  =\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{(\frac{2x^2}{x^3} - \frac{x^3}{x^3} )^\frac{1}{3}} $$

$$ = (-1)^\frac{1}{3}$$

So, $$p = (-1)^\frac{1}{3}$$

And 
$$q =  \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{f(x)-px} $$

This would be $$  \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{(2x^2-x^3)^\frac{1}{3}} -  (-1)^\frac{1}{3}x$$

In Wolframalpha this lim has a complex solution. Does this function have a linear asymptote ? Can a real number function (from $$R -> R$$ ) can have a complex asymptote? I guess not, because then it wouldn't be linear anymore.

Comment: $2x^2-x^3<0$ when $x>2$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand this. When x > 2 , then $$2x^2-x^3 <0$$

Comment: BY analogy to $\sqrt(x)$ when $x<0$, how do you define $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$?

Comment: $$ x^{1/3} $$ is the third root of x. I define it from real numbers to real numbers. What I do not understand. What does this have to do with the linear asymptote or am I just confused?

Comment: @Blnpwr: The limit for $q$ is incorrect. Should be $\lim_{x\to+\infty}((2x^2-x^3)^{1/3}-(-1)^{1/3}x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}((2x^2-x^3)^{1/3}+x)$.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan I wrote it down on my paper correctly, i just forgot it here(edited). But the result is the same, the lim is a complex one. And a complex q cannot be linear, I guess.

Comment: @Blnpwr: I guess WolframAlpha doesn't know which root to take and ends up with a complex one. You can do better.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Do you have a tip for me ? Should I use the third binomial formula ? $$ (a-b)(a+b) = a^2-b^2 ? $$

Comment: @Blnpwr: You may rewrite the expression as $x(1-\sqrt[3]{1-2/x})$

Comment: @SergeiGolovan thank mate, but where is the +1 ? If I multiply the whole statement in the brackets with x , then I won't have +1 anymore.

Comment: You must tell WA that you mean the *real* cube root, not the principal value of the complex cube root. To that effect, use `cbrt` (or `surd`) rather than $1/3$ exponents, like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(cbrt(2+x%5E2+-+x%5E3)+-+cbrt(-1)x)+for+x+to+infinity) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$q=\lim_{x\to\infty}(2x^2-x^3)^{1/3}+x=\frac23$$

I'll leave you to show this with the tip that $a^{1/3}+b^{1/3}=\frac{a+b}{a^{2/3}-(ab)^{1/3}+b^{2/3}}$ because this is not actually the main part of my answer.  Instead, I want to provide you with a new method for such an expansion known as the binomial expansion.  First, we want the largest powers to be at the front, so,

$$f(x)=-(x^3-2x^2)^{1/3}$$

Now we apply the binomial expansion theorem:

$$(a-b)^{1/3}=a^{1/3}-\frac13ba^{-2/3}-\frac29b^2a^{-5/3}+\dots$$

Let $a=x^3$ and $b=2x^2$,

$$f(x)=-\left(x-\frac23-\frac89x^{-1}+\dots\right)=-x+\frac23+\frac89x^{-1}+\dots$$

which not only returns the linear asymptote but also better asymptotes as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a great answer!

Comment: @Blnpwr Your welcome!  Have a happy New year!

Comment: But when is $$ x -> \infty $$ then, -x also goes to $$ - \infty  $$ how can one get $$ \frac{2}{3} $$ ?

Comment: Hey, never mind, I got it :D I wish you a happy new year and thank you for your really really helpful and smart answer.

Comment: @Blnpwr :D No problem.  You sure you don't need help with it?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the generalized
binomial theorem:

$\begin{array}\\
f(x) 
&= (2x^2-x^3)^{1/3}\\
&= (-x)(1-\frac{2}{x})^{1/3}\\
&= (-x)(1-\frac{2}{x}\frac13+(-\frac{2}{x})^2\frac13 (-\frac23)+O(\frac1{x^3}))\\
&= (-x)(1-\frac{2}{3x}-\frac{8}{9x^2}+O(\frac1{x^3}))\\
&= -x+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{8}{9x}+O(\frac1{x^2}))\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: But when is $$ x -> \infty $$ then, -x also goes to $$ - \infty  $$ how can one get $$ \frac{2}{3} $$ ?

Comment: $f(x)<0$ for $x>2$.

Comment: Isn't this basically a copy of my answer?

Comment: Done independently.